# SQL - Summarizing "Nested" Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working my SQL and cannot quite figure how to get what I am looking for, and I could not find a similar question asked

Every field for "Node Sid" has a "Parent Sid" field. Some Node Side are listed as multiple times, which is not a problem. I am having an issue finding the total number of (direct and indirect) descendants or "children" for each node SID.

Here is an example of the data

```
Node Sid   Parent Sid
2011       2010
2012       2010
2013       2010
2014       2010
2010       2009
2009       2008
```

In this instance how could I find the total number nested under 2009. My current SQL gives me each individual Node Sid, but not the total values nested underneath.

```
SELECT COUNT(PARENT_NODE_SID) AS "NODES"
FROM NODE_V
GROUP BY PARENT_NODE_SID
```

The result I am looking for would be like this

```
Node Sid   Count of Node Sid
    2011       0
    2012       0
    2013       0
    2014       0
    2010       4
    2009       5
```

In essence, the Count of Node Sid would include all of the times it was listed as a "Parent Sid" and also all of the times the Node Sids that listed it were "Parent Sid"

Comment: Could you clarify what result you expect exactly?

Comment: So by "total amount" you mean the total number of nodes (including the parent sid itself) in the subtree starting at each parent sid?

Comment: Stefano Zanini - See updated post above (Sorry for the lack of clarity)

Comment: Mathguy - Yes, that would do the trick

Comment: Question then - why doesn't the output also show 2008, with the count of 6? Do you only want the count for nodes that have a parent, and not for the "top" of the hierarchy?

Comment: And - no, that doesn't match your "desired output". If the answer for 2012 is 1, this means 2012 itself is counted. But for 2010 you show the result of 4, which is the number of children. If 2010 itself must also be included, then the result should be 5 for 2010 (and 6 for 2009, and 7 for 2008). Or is the rule more complicated - show 1 for the leaves, but only the number of descendants (without including the node itself) if the node has children? You won't get a good answer if your problem is not clear to begin with.

Comment: It goes about three levels deep - the "top" of the hierarchy the parent node value is always 0. The "top" count would presumably include everything and could function as the total count of all nodes. This ends the cycle because 0 is never a Node Sid

Comment: Mathguy - Good point - I am mistaken and apologies for the ignorance there. they would have "0" when they are at the "bottom" and not one. I shall correct the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with inputs (Node_Sid, Parent_Sid) as (
       select 2011, 2010 from dual union all
       select 2012, 2010 from dual union all
       select 2013, 2010 from dual union all
       select 2014, 2010 from dual union all
       select 2010, 2009 from dual union all
       select 2009, 2008 from dual
     )
select   node_sid, count(*) as cnt
from     (
           select     connect_by_root(parent_sid) as node_sid
           from       inputs
           connect by prior node_sid = parent_sid
         )
group by node_sid
union all
select node_sid, 0 as cnt
from   inputs
where  node_sid not in (select parent_sid from inputs)
;

NODE_SID  CNT
--------  ---
    2009    5
    2010    4
    2008    6
    2012    0
    2013    0
    2014    0
    2011    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question completely, but could you be looking for something like this?

```
SELECT PARENT_NODE_SID,COUNT(*)
FROM NODE_V
GROUP BY PARENT_NODE_SID
ORDER BY PARENT_NODE_SID
```

Comment: That is helpful for sure - the only piece I am missing is that it would make my count for Node Sid 2009 only come out to "1" because it was only listed a 2009 once. It would not include everything in the subtree